# Using existing git with TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I am using the new Team Foundation Server 2013 Express with git. I created a new team project and TFS automatically creates a new git repository for me. But I want to continue using my existing git repository on a separated version control server. Is there any way to configure the TFS so it uses push and pull to receive the repository from a different server instead of hosting it on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to it as a local repository, and then use the command line to deal with your 3rd party hosted repo. This method doesn't really use TFS for anything however. What are you wanting to accomplish with TFS?